# MySQL: Compare differences between two tables

Tags: sql, mysql

Same as [oracle diff: how to compare two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688537/) except in mysql.

> Suppose I have two tables, t1 and t2 which are identical in layout but which may contain different data.
>
> What's the best way to diff these two tables?

To be more precise, I'm trying to figure out a simple SQL query that tells me if data from one row in t1 is different from the data from the corresponding row in t2

It appears I cannot use the intersect nor minus. When I try

```
SELECT * FROM robot intersect SELECT * FROM tbd_robot
```

I get an error code:

> [Error Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM tbd_robot' at line 1

Am I doing something syntactically wrong? If not, is there another query I can use?

Edit: Also, I'm querying through a free version DbVisualizer. Not sure if that might be a factor.

Comment: I made a free tool to generate the ALTER statements to make the second table the same as the first one http://www.tablediff.com still in alpha.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`INTERSECT` needs to be emulated in `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  'robot' AS `set`, r.*
FROM    robot r
WHERE   ROW(r.col1, r.col2, …) NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  col1, col2, ...
        FROM    tbd_robot
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT  'tbd_robot' AS `set`, t.*
FROM    tbd_robot t
WHERE   ROW(t.col1, t.col2, …) NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  col1, col2, ...
        FROM    robot
        )
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Apparently, I didn't need the "as set" part but it works now

Comment: Superb!. This is what I was searching for.
And I also get to know about ROW(...) IN(...) thing now

Comment: Any idea how to do it without having to write every fields?

Comment: Thank you kind, Sir! You've saved me from going through 2 millions of records to find the differences between 2 tables.

Answer (score 82):

You can construct the intersection manually using UNION. It's easy if you have some unique field in both tables, e.g. ID:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM T2)

UNION

SELECT * FROM T2
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM T1)
```

If you don't have a unique value, you can still expand the above code to check for all fields instead of just the ID, and use AND to connect them (e.g. ID NOT IN(...) AND OTHER_FIELD NOT IN(...) etc)

Comment: elegant solution, @Roee Adler!

Answer (score 10):

```
 select t1.user_id,t2.user_id 
 from t1 left join t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
 and t1.username=t2.username 
 and t1.first_name=t2.first_name 
 and t1.last_name=t2.last_name
```

try this. This will compare your table and find all matching pairs, if any mismatch return NULL on left.

Comment: This is the best and most performant answer for the question! Thanks!

Comment: be sure to use ifnull(t1.field_name, 1) = ifnull(t2.field_name, 1) to make sure you eliminate false positives.

Comment: if t2 has additional records nor present in t1, will those not be missed by this query?

Answer (score 8):

I found another solution in this [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/compare-two-tables-to-find-unmatched-records-mysql.aspx)

```
SELECT MIN (tbl_name) AS tbl_name, PK, column_list
FROM
 (
  SELECT ' source_table ' as tbl_name, S.PK, S.column_list
  FROM source_table AS S
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'destination_table' as tbl_name, D.PK, D.column_list
  FROM destination_table AS D 
)  AS alias_table
GROUP BY PK, column_list
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY PK
```

Comment: hi, +1. I was looking for the exact same thing.

Comment: @haim-evgi it ignore duplicates..suppose a table has a row and another table have such two rows, so it will ignore this. of-course, Considering there are no PK fields in both tables. How would we handle in this case?

Comment: I had to use ``COUNT(*)`` instead of ``COUNT (*)``.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Haim's answer I created a PHP code to test and display all the differences between two databases. 
This will also display if a table is present in source or test databases.
You have to change with your details the <> variables content.

```
<?php

    $User = "<DatabaseUser>";
    $Pass = "<DatabasePassword>";
    $SourceDB = "<SourceDatabase>";
    $TestDB = "<DatabaseToTest>";

    $link = new mysqli( "p:". "localhost", $User, $Pass, "" );

    if ( mysqli_connect_error() ) {

        die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno() .') '. mysqli_connect_error());

    }

    mysqli_set_charset( $link, "utf8" );
    mb_language( "uni" );
    mb_internal_encoding( "UTF-8" );

    $sQuery = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="'. $SourceDB .'";';

    $SourceDB_Content = query( $link, $sQuery );

    if ( !is_array( $SourceDB_Content) ) {

        echo "Table $SourceDB cannot be accessed";
        exit(0);

    }

    $sQuery = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="'. $TestDB .'";';

    $TestDB_Content = query( $link, $sQuery );

    if ( !is_array( $TestDB_Content) ) {

        echo "Table $TestDB cannot be accessed";
        exit(0);

    }

    $SourceDB_Tables = array();
    foreach( $SourceDB_Content as $item ) {
        $SourceDB_Tables[] = $item["TABLE_NAME"];
    }

    $TestDB_Tables = array();
    foreach( $TestDB_Content as $item ) {
        $TestDB_Tables[] = $item["TABLE_NAME"];
    }
    //var_dump( $SourceDB_Tables, $TestDB_Tables );
    $LookupTables = array_merge( $SourceDB_Tables, $TestDB_Tables );
    $NoOfDiscrepancies = 0;
    echo "

    <table border='1' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>Table</td>
        <td>Found in $SourceDB (". count( $SourceDB_Tables ) .")</td>
        <td>Found in $TestDB (". count( $TestDB_Tables ) .")</td>
        <td>Test result</td>
    <tr>

    ";

    foreach( $LookupTables as $table ) {

        $FoundInSourceDB = in_array( $table, $SourceDB_Tables ) ? 1 : 0;
        $FoundInTestDB = in_array( $table, $TestDB_Tables ) ? 1 : 0;
        echo "

    <tr>
        <td>$table</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' ". ($FoundInSourceDB == 1 ? "checked" : "") ."></td> 
        <td><input type='checkbox' ". ($FoundInTestDB == 1 ? "checked" : "") ."></td>   
        <td>". compareTables( $SourceDB, $TestDB, $table ) ."</td>  
    </tr>   
        ";

    }

    echo "

    </table>
    <br><br>
    No of discrepancies found: $NoOfDiscrepancies
    ";


    function query( $link, $q ) {

        $result = mysqli_query( $link, $q );

        $errors = mysqli_error($link);
        if ( $errors > "" ) {

            echo $errors;
            exit(0);

        }

        if( $result == false ) return false;
        else if ( $result === true ) return true;
        else {

            $rset = array();

            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {

                $rset[] = $row;

            }

            return $rset;

        }

    }

    function compareTables( $source, $test, $table ) {

        global $link;
        global $NoOfDiscrepancies;

        $sQuery = "

    SELECT column_name,ordinal_position,data_type,column_type FROM
    (
        SELECT
            column_name,ordinal_position,
            data_type,column_type,COUNT(1) rowcount
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE
        (
            (table_schema='$source' AND table_name='$table') OR
            (table_schema='$test' AND table_name='$table')
        )
        AND table_name IN ('$table')
        GROUP BY
            column_name,ordinal_position,
            data_type,column_type
        HAVING COUNT(1)=1
    ) A;    

        ";

        $result = query( $link, $sQuery );

        $data = "";
        if( is_array( $result ) && count( $result ) > 0 ) {

            $NoOfDiscrepancies++;
            $data = "<table><tr><td>column_name</td><td>ordinal_position</td><td>data_type</td><td>column_type</td></tr>";

            foreach( $result as $item ) {

                $data .= "<tr><td>". $item["column_name"] ."</td><td>". $item["ordinal_position"] ."</td><td>". $item["data_type"] ."</td><td>". $item["column_type"] ."</td></tr>";

            }

            $data .= "</table>";

            return $data;

        }
        else {

            return "Checked but no discrepancies found!";

        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Asking for +1 reduces your chances of getting it. Stack Overflow has a review queue, people are encouraged to up vote Q&A's they like. a decent answer may get an upvote or two. There's a bronze badge for answers that 10 upvotes ("nice answer"), 25 upvotes: "good answer" (silver badge) and 100 upvotes "great answer" (gold badge). upvotes usuallytrickle in slowly usually, depending on question, answer and topic. It can take weeks, months or years to get a large number of upvotes as not that many people may see the question or your answer, or might be competitive answers that steal the show.

Comment: I recommend the [2-Minute Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). That will give you more info about what goes on here. Sounds like your'e up for the challenge, learn quickly and do good work. You should be able to grow your reputation and site privileges quickly, and work on some badges to to show your contributions as well. Good luck! And welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Problem below, is to compare table before and after i do big update!.

If you use **Linux**, you can use commands as follow:

In terminal,

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -p schema_name_here table_name_here > /home/ubuntu/database_dumps/dump_table_before_running_update.sql

mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -p schema_name_here table_name_here > /home/ubuntu/database_dumps/dump_table_after_running_update.sql

diff -uP /home/ubuntu/database_dumps/dump_some_table_after_running_update.sql /home/ubuntu/database_dumps/dump_table_before_running_update.sql > /home/ubuntu/database_dumps/diff.txt
```

You will need online tools *for*

- Formatting SQL exported from the dumps,

e.g http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm [Not the best I've seen]

- We have **diff.txt**, you have to take manually the + - showing inside, which is 1 line of insert statements, that has the values.
- Do diff online for the 2 lines - & + in **diff.txt**, past them in online diff tool

e.g https://www.diffchecker.com [you can save and share it, and has no limit on file size!]

**Note**: be extra careful if its sensitive/production data!

[image: diff preview]

[image: How diff.txt will look like]

Answer (score 1):

you can try The big data comparison platform in https://github.com/zhugezifang/dataCompare

this is a introduction of it

**Design and practice of open source big data comparison platform**

**1. Background & current situation**

In the process of developing large numbers, it is often encountered that data migration or upgrade, or different business parties have processed data according to their needs, but think that the data on both sides is still the same, so it will be necessary to manually compare the data. So is the data on both sides consistent? If not, what are the differences?

If there is no platform, you need to manually write some SQL scripts for comparison, and there is no evaluation standard. This is inefficient.

"Alibaba's Road to Big Data" actually mentions such a platform, but because it is not used externally, the introduction in the book is relatively simple. Based on previous work experience, a big data comparison platform was developed to assist in verifying data, named dataCompare.

Main solutions:

(1) Verify data and data comparison, which wastes great labor costs

(2) Without a set of standards, the results of verification are difficult to evaluate

(3) Automatic data verification and comparison can be achieved by interface interaction, check or low-code
[enter image description here][1]

**2. Purpose**

(1) Automatic data verification and comparison can be achieved by interface interaction, check or low-code.

(2) The data team's data comparison efficiency is increased by at least about 50%.

(3) A set of unified data verification scheme to meet the standard specifications of data verification and comparison

**3. System architecture design**

**4. The current version has implemented the following functions**

(1) Low-code simple configuration completes the core function of data comparison

(2) Data magnitude comparison and data consistency comparison

**5. Follow-up Development Plan**

(1) Discrepancy case finding
(2) Data pointer detection---- enumeration value detection, range detection, numerical detection, primary key mode detection
(3) Data comparison task is scheduled and automatically scheduled
(4) Automatically send an email report to the comparison results

**6. The core code is opening in githup**

https://github.com/zhugezifang/dataCompare

[enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

Based on Haim's answer here's a simplified example if you're looking to compare values that exist in BOTH tables, otherwise if there's a row in one table but not the other it will also return it....

Took me a couple of hours to figure out. Here's a fully tested simply query for comparing "tbl_a" and "tbl_b"

```
SELECT ID, col
FROM
(
    SELECT
    tbl_a.ID, tbl_a.col FROM tbl_a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    tbl_b.ID, tbl_b.col FROM tbl_b
) t
WHERE ID IN (select ID from tbl_a) AND ID IN (select ID from tbl_b)
GROUP BY
ID, col
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
 ORDER BY ID
```

So you need to add the extra "where in" clause:

> WHERE ID IN (select ID from tbl_a) AND ID IN (select ID from tbl_b)

---

**Also:**

For ease of reading if you want to indicate the table names you can use the following:

```
SELECT tbl, ID, col
FROM
(
    SELECT
    tbl_a.ID, tbl_a.col, "name_to_display1" as "tbl" FROM tbl_a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    tbl_b.ID, tbl_b.col, "name_to_display2" as "tbl" FROM tbl_b
) t
WHERE ID IN (select ID from tbl_a) AND ID IN (select ID from tbl_b)
GROUP BY
ID, col
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
 ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user my own developed tool

https://github.com/hardeepvicky/MySql-Schema-Compare

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above answer but found that if one table has null values and the second table has values in a column then the intersect code above does not report this fact.

```
select p.pcn,p.period,p.account_no,p.ytd_debit,a.ytd_debit 
-- select count(*) -- 157,283
from Plex.account_period_balance p -- 157,283/202207,148,998
join Azure.account_period_balance a  -- 157,283/202207,148,998
on p.pcn = a.pcn 
and p.period = a.period 
and p.account_no = a.account_no -- 157,283 
where p.period_display = a.period_display -- 157,283 
and p.debit = a.debit  -- 157,283 
-- and p.ytd_debit = a.ytd_debit -- 148,998
-- and p.ytd_debit != a.ytd_debit -- 0
```

Comment: The other answers are not always "above". Sure, they are while you type your answer - but then they're sorted in the page once posted. Criteria are "Trending", "Highest score", "Date modified", "Date created". Your answer will be placed in the page according to this parameter.