# How to improve MySql query that trying to find distinct values from two tables?

Tags: mysql, distinct

```
SELECT distinct  source_IP, timestamp FROM  tb1 , tb2 WHERE tb1.source_IP 
not in ( SELECT source_IP FROM tb2 WHERE tb1.source_IP = tb2.source_IP) 
AND tb1.timestamp not in 
( SELECT timestamp FROM tb2 WHERE tb1.timestamp = tb2.timestamp )
```

The above query has been written to compare attributes (source_IP and timestamp) of tb1 with the same attributes in tb2 and select only the distinct ones that belong to tb1. However, this query is working fine, but I am looking for better way to make it more efficient, since there are three queries in the statement. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks God, this query is working fine:

```
SELECT source_IP, timestamp FROM tb1 WHERE  source_IP NOT IN (SELECT source_IP FROM tb2) 
AND timestamp NOT IN (SELECT timestamp FROM tb2)
```

Thanks to Roee Adler
[compare differences between two tables in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/compare-differences-between-two-tables-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists`. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   tb1.source_IP, 
   tb1.timestamp 
FROM 
   tb1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT NULL FROM tb2 
    WHERE tb1.source_IP=tb2.source_IP AND tb1.timestamp=tb2.timestamp)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine, but with "EXISTS" instead of "NOT EXISTS", since it will return NULL in case of finding any similarity.

Comment: Do you mean the `SELECT NULL`. You can have what ever you want there `SELECT 1`,`SELECT 'tut'` or what ever