# Comparing multiple columns between two different rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi this is my first question so hope it makes sense!

I need to compare two rows against each other (from the same table - quote) which have multiple columns.
eg.

```
aagrnum aqtenum atrmres  astlamt  atrmdat  aqtests .... etc
abc123  1       C        5000     20140102 Y
abc123  2       C        5000     20130102 N
```

what I have so far is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (SELECT * FROM quote a
  WHERE a.aagrnum = 'abc123'
  AND a.aqtenum = 1) c
UNION SELECT *
FROM
 (SELECT * FROM quote b
  WHERE b.aagrnum = 'abc123'
  AND b.aqtenum = 2) d
WHERE c.atrmres <> d.atrmres
AND c.astlamt <> d.astlamt
AND c.atrmdat <> d.atrmdat
```

However I get the message that table C is undefined.
I hope to do the comparisons across multiple columns and have nothing returned if these compared columns are all equal and just the two rows if they are not equal. So in the example table above I would have two rows displayed as atrmdat is not equal in both rows, however it does not matter that aqtests is not equal across them both.

Does anyone have an idea of how I may do this? I will be very grateful! Thanks!

Comment: Can you change your example to be closer to your real data? What you're trying to do, and what you should be trying to do are very different at this point, and you could get more useful help by not obfuscating your problem so much.  Real tables, and column names will allow others to guide you closer to what you should be doing to get what you want.

Comment: Yes, please provide extracts of both tables and a concrete example of the result that you want to get!

Comment: The Where clause only applies to the latest Select. I'ld recommend that you try using Joins instead. However like previous commentators stated, it's pretty hard to figure out what you actually want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [compare differences between two tables in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/compare-differences-between-two-tables-in-mysql)