# difference in data of mysql same tables of different databases

Tags: mysql, database, difference

I want to find out the differences of two same structured tables but in different databases,One is master table & i want to sync all other similar tables in different databases with it.

For example t1 table in db1 and t2 table in db2, want to find out difference between t1 & t2 using mysql.

Comment: Are these 2 databases on the same server? Then try [compare differences between two tables in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/compare-differences-between-two-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: thanks for reply , but it seems that both tables are in same db ! and as i have to many dbs, so some of them are not in same server.

Comment: If they are on the same server, you can use `dbname1.tablename` and `dbname2.tablename` in the (same) query. If they are not, you have to put them on the same server. You can e.g. use federated tables, replication, or, if it is not a realtime issue, mysqldump (or some scripting), on the other hand, it might be easier then to mark changes to your table and copy them by script.