# How to find MySQL Views or Triggers that have been added or updated in the last hour?

Tags: mysql

I need to track database changes. Can already get this information for Tables, Functions and Stored Procedures from the relevant INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables. But in the case of Views and Triggers there doesn't seem to be data for CREATED or MODIFIED DateTime. How can this be achieved?

Comment: No mysql doesn't facilitate such tracker. I may suggest you to put those triggers and views in a table. On table change, you will run a trigger to change the specific trigger/view code. Before that you have to dump your previous trigger/view in `dump` trigger/view table.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 5):

For a trigger's "created" date/time, there is a `CREATED` field in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS`. But according to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers-table.html), this is only correctly populated in MySQL version 5.7.2 or higher:

> CREATED: The date and time when the trigger was created. This is a
>   TIMESTAMP(2) value (with a fractional part in hundredths of seconds)
>   for triggers created in MySQL 5.7.2 or later, NULL for triggers
>   created prior to 5.7.2.

But unfortunately there isn't an equivalent "updated" or "deleted" date/time column and the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` table does not have any of these. My first thought for a possible workaround was to create triggers on the relevant `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables but unfortunately this doesn't seem to be possible as the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables are actually more like "views" (but not based on actual tables). Hence the following "next best" solution...

**Workaround: "Snapshot" tables**

Create a scheduled event using the MySQL event scheduler that runs every hour and runs queries to copy the contents of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` tables into "snapshot" tables in a local database:

```
-- Remove existing event of this name if there is one
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS update_snapshots;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT update_snapshots ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR 
    DO BEGIN
        -- Drop the current snapshot table (if there is one)
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS triggers_snapshot;
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS views_snapshot;

        -- Recreate snapshot tables
        CREATE TABLE triggers_snapshot AS SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS;
        CREATE TABLE views_snapshot AS SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;

-- Turn the MySQL event scheduler on
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

-- Show all events (to check it was created successfully and its status)
SHOW EVENTS;
```

Then at any point the current `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables can be queried and compared with the snapshots using a technique such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/compare-differences-between-two-tables-in-mysql#950505):

```
SELECT  'new' AS `status`, s.*
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS s
WHERE   ROW(s.TRIGGER_CATALOG, s.TRIGGER_SCHEMA, s.TRIGGER_NAME, s.EVENT_MANIPULATION,
            s.EVENT_OBJECT_CATALOG, s.EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA, s.EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE,
            s.ACTION_ORDER, s.ACTION_CONDITION, s.ACTION_STATEMENT, s.ACTION_ORIENTATION,
            s.ACTION_TIMING, s.ACTION_REFERENCE_OLD_TABLE, s.ACTION_REFERENCE_NEW_TABLE,
            s.ACTION_REFERENCE_OLD_ROW, s.ACTION_REFERENCE_NEW_ROW, s.CREATED, s.SQL_MODE,
            s.DEFINER, s.CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT, s.COLLATION_CONNECTION, 
            s.DATABASE_COLLATION) NOT IN (SELECT * FROM triggers_snapshot)
UNION ALL
SELECT  'old' AS `status`, t.*
FROM    triggers_snapshot t
WHERE   ROW(t.TRIGGER_CATALOG, t.TRIGGER_SCHEMA, t.TRIGGER_NAME, t.EVENT_MANIPULATION,
            t.EVENT_OBJECT_CATALOG, t.EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA, t.EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE,
            t.ACTION_ORDER, t.ACTION_CONDITION, t.ACTION_STATEMENT, t.ACTION_ORIENTATION,
            t.ACTION_TIMING, t.ACTION_REFERENCE_OLD_TABLE, t.ACTION_REFERENCE_NEW_TABLE,
            t.ACTION_REFERENCE_OLD_ROW, t.ACTION_REFERENCE_NEW_ROW, t.CREATED, t.SQL_MODE,
            t.DEFINER, t.CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT, t.COLLATION_CONNECTION, 
            t.DATABASE_COLLATION) NOT IN (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS)
```

...and...

```
SELECT  'new' AS `status`, s.*
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS s
WHERE   ROW(s.TABLE_CATALOG, s.TABLE_SCHEMA, s.TABLE_NAME, s.VIEW_DEFINITION,
            s.CHECK_OPTION, s.IS_UPDATABLE, s.DEFINER, s.SECURITY_TYPE,
            s.CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT, s.COLLATION_CONNECTION)
        NOT IN (SELECT * FROM views_snapshot)
UNION ALL
SELECT  'old' AS `status`, t.*
FROM    views_snapshot t
WHERE   ROW(t.TABLE_CATALOG, t.TABLE_SCHEMA, t.TABLE_NAME, t.VIEW_DEFINITION,
            t.CHECK_OPTION, t.IS_UPDATABLE, t.DEFINER, t.SECURITY_TYPE,
            t.CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT, t.COLLATION_CONNECTION)
        NOT IN (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS)
```

**Limitations**

These won't tell you exactly when the changes were made and doesn't exactly cover the last hour - only the time since the last snapshot, which could be any time in the last hour. If more accuracy than this is required, the snapshot interval could be decreased - but this would add complexity as potentially multiple snapshots would then need to be maintained and the correct one used for the comparison.

Comment: by using above code , we can not get views which are updated. Actually i am need to sync database among developers so i need to find views, triggers, functions, procedure updated or created

Answer (score 1):

Go to your data directory and check the modified date time

Answer (score 1):

If it's purely structural changes and you just need to track them, then another approach is to use mysqldump which will give you all the current structure:

```
mysqldump --no-data --skip-comments dbname
```

With the `skip-comments` option it'll be consistent over time and only change if the structure changes. You can diff it:

```
mysqldump --no-data --skip-comments dbname > /tmp/schema1.sql
# (wait)
mysqldump --no-data --skip-comments dbname > /tmp/schema2.sql
diff /tmp/schema1.sql /tmp/schema2.sql
```

Or even put a single file into a version control system, which will let you use hooks & other 'change triggers':

```
mysqldump --no-data --skip-comments dbname > schema.sql && git commit -m "MySQL schema change" schema.sql
```

Obviously these methods don't give you any information on precisely when, or who/why changes were made.