# Find the non matching data fromtwo same tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables i.e. Records and Student_Records with 33 columns inside.
I want to extract the non matching data from the two tables which query should i use??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/compare-differences-between-two-tables-in-mysql

Comment: Actually i used that query bt it shows me operand contains 33 columns

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ID FROM Records EXCEPT SELECT RecordsID FROM Student_Records