# Compare two query results and output difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries against the same table:

1. SELECT * FROM table WHERE fileName='x';
2. SELECT * FROM table WHERE fileName='y';

Now, I am trying to compare the result that is being returned by these queries. There is no ID I could compare against but I need to compare each column.

I was trying to modify this approach, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/compare-differences-between-two-tables-in-mysql):

```
SELECT  'robot' AS `set`, r.*
FROM    robot r
WHERE   ROW(r.col1, r.col2, …) NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    tbd_robot
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT  'tbd_robot' AS `set`, t.*
FROM    tbd_robot t
WHERE   ROW(t.col1, t.col2, …) NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    robot
    )
```

I am not sure how to modify this code correctly. My attempts to change the table names to the same table but adding a `WHERE` clause failed in SQL exceptions.

Is this even the best route to take? Maybe there is an even more clever way to compare two query results and output the differences?

Thank you very much for your help in advance :-)

EDIT:

Sample Data:

```
ID | fileName | firstName | lastName | address  
1  | x.txt    | John      | Doe      | 1 Test st  
2  | x.txt    | Jane      | Doe      | 3 Test st  
3  | y.txt    | John      | Doe      | 2 Test st  
4  | y.txt    | Jane      | Doe      | 3 Test st
```

Since the address differs where ID = 3, this is the row that should be returned.

Comment: There might be a few ways to do this, but first you need to clarify... what do you mean compare the two tables? What criteria specifically are you looking to compare against? It might help if you post some samples of your data and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Added some sample data as requested by @SandPiper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `group by` is a simpler approach:

```
select col1, col2, col3, . . .,
       sum(fileName = 'x') as count_x,
       sum(fileName = '7') as count_y
from table t
where fileName in ('x', 'y')
group by col1, col2, col3, . . .;
```

For the columns that you specify, you will get the count of rows with `'x'` and `'y'`.

You can just output the differences by putting `having count_x <> count_y` at the end of the query.