# Get difference between two tables of records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am running a difference between two tables of records in MySQL.  Unfortunately it is not returning ALL diff records,

SELECT * FROM A
WHERE (Dept, EmpNum) NOT IN (SELECT Dept,EmpNum FROM B)

This returns all records Where EmpNum is unique to A, but it does NOT return all records in A where EmpNum AND Dept don't exist.

So for example, in A, the following records below don't show up in B, but 0451, 1234 is not returned

`A

Dept    EmpNum

0450    1234
0451    1234
0452    1235`

SELECT  'robot' AS `set`, r.*
FROM    employee_status_ext r
WHERE   ROW(r.EmpNum, r.Dept) NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  EmpNum, Dept
        FROM    employee_status_ext_archive
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT  'employee_status_ext_archive' AS `set`, t.*
FROM    employee_status_ext_archive t
WHERE   ROW(t.EmpNum, t.Dept) NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  EmpNum, Dept
        FROM    employee_status_ext
        )

Comment: Look at this topic [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/compare-differences-between-two-tables-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/compare-differences-between-two-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: I tried that, but I get the same problem.  Where the it's only returning records where Dept is unique, not where EmpNum/Dept are unique. Do I need an index on them?

Comment: I updated my code above to show the new query I tried off your link. It still missing the record 0451 - 1234

Comment: Nevermind, MVG1984, you were correct in the first place. I didn't realize there was another column that had relevant changes. Please ignore the above two comments.  Your answer was right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare differences between two tables in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/compare-differences-between-two-tables-in-mysql)